# java--Creating non-random shapes per event

Tags: java, arrays, swing, rectangles

I've been working on creating shapes such as rectangles using an ArrayList in java. I'm trying to get the rectangles to appear in the panel one at a time and slowly build an actual image. I've had no problem getting them to appear and stay as random rects (location, size, color)...but when I attempt to make these rects static...it all falls apart. Suggestions will be welcome.

```
Full code so far below:

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.List;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.sound.midi.ControllerEventListener;
import javax.sound.midi.MidiEvent;
import javax.sound.midi.MidiSystem;
import javax.sound.midi.Sequence;
import javax.sound.midi.Sequencer;
import javax.sound.midi.ShortMessage;
import javax.sound.midi.Track;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class GraphicMusicPlayer
                implements ControllerEventListener {
    static JFrame f = new JFrame("Graphic Music");
    static MyDrawPanel myPanel;


    @Override
    public void controlChange(ShortMessage event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GraphicMusicPlayer mini = new GraphicMusicPlayer();
        mini.go();
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    public void setUpGui() {
        // Create the panel within the frame
        myPanel = new MyDrawPanel();
        f.setContentPane(myPanel);
        f.setBounds(700, 700, 800, 800);
        f.setVisible(true);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
    public void go() {
        setUpGui();

        try {
            // Make and open a sequencer.
            Sequencer sequencer = MidiSystem.getSequencer();
            sequencer.open();

            // Register for events. 127 is the event.
            sequencer.addControllerEventListener(myPanel, new int[] {93});
            Sequence seq = new Sequence(Sequence.PPQ, 4);
            Track track = seq.createTrack();

            int r = 0;

            int[] tonesList = new int[] {
                            65, 64, 65, 64, 65, 60, 63, 61,
                            58,65, 64, 65, 64, 65, 60, 63, 61,
                            58};

            for (int i = 0; i < 18; i +=1) {
                r = tonesList[i];
                if (r>0){

                track.add(makeEvent(144,5,r,93,i));//144 = NOTE_ON
                track.add(makeEvent(176,5,93,125,i));//176 = get event
                track.add(makeEvent(128,5,r,46,i+1));//128 = NOTE_OFF
            }//end loop

            sequencer.setSequence(seq);
            sequencer.setTempoInBPM(30);
            sequencer.start();

            }
        }
            catch (Exception ex) {ex.printStackTrace();}

    }
    public static MidiEvent makeEvent(int comd, int chan, int one, int two, int tick) {

        MidiEvent event = null;
        try {
            ShortMessage a = new ShortMessage();
            a.setMessage(comd, chan, one, two);
            event = new MidiEvent(a, tick);
        } catch (Exception e) { }
        return event;
    }
     @SuppressWarnings("serial")
    class MyDrawPanel extends JPanel implements ControllerEventListener {

            boolean msg = false;

            ArrayList<Rectangle> rectangleList = new ArrayList<Rectangle>();
            Map<Rectangle, Color> rectangleColors = new HashMap<Rectangle, Color>();
            public void addRectangle(Rectangle rect){
                rectangleList.add(rect);
            }

            public void controlChange(ShortMessage event) {
                msg  = true;
                repaint();
            }

            public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                super.paintComponent(g);
                setBackground(Color.BLACK);


                while (msg) {

                Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
                int red = (int) (Math.random() * 250);
                int green = (int) (Math.random() * 250);
                int blue = (int) (Math.random() * 250);
                Color rcolor = new Color(red, green, blue);
                int x = (int) (Math.random() * 750);
                int y = (int) (Math.random() * 750);
                int width = (int) (Math.random() * 100);
                int height = (int) (Math.random() * 100);

                Rectangle nextRect = new Rectangle(x,y,width,height);
                rectangleList.add(nextRect);
                g.setColor(rcolor);
                rectangleColors.put(nextRect, rcolor);


                //paint all of the rectangles
                for (Rectangle rect : rectangleList){

                    Color rectColor = rectangleColors.get(rect);
                    g.setColor(rectColor);
                    // Fill the rectangle with the rectangle color
                    g2.fill(rect);

                }
                msg = false;
            }

        }
     }
}
```

Comment: You will want to make your question much more specific. Posting requirements and a request for recommendations is quite broad and may be too broad for this site. Regarding making images stay, don't create the random images in paintComponent. Make them elsewhere and store them in an ArrayList of some type. Either that or simply draw them on a BufferedImage, one that you display within paintComponent.

Comment: Also this `while (msg) {` makes no sense whatsoever. What purpose is that supposed to serve?

Comment: Animation in Swing should be done through the use of a Swing `Timer` - start by having a look at [How to use Swing Timers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html). You have to think of them as "pseudo loops", on each tick of the timer is an iteration of the loop

Comment: `paint` can be called at any time (and often in quick succession), it should focus on painting the current state and should never modify the state, so you attempt to do this inside the paint method is misguided

Comment: Thanks--the while (msg) is needed to bridge the eventListener to the graphics. With each event, the rect is drawn.  As I said, it works fine for random rect generation but I am having trouble making the rect non-random.

Comment: *"the while (msg) is needed to bridge the eventListener to the graphics"* - the `eventListener` should update the state and trigger a paint cycle by calling `repaint`, trying to loop inside the `paint` method like this is not a good idea and paint should run as fast as possible

Comment: I will definitely try these ideas! Thank you.